# How to get a variable from a private method to a static method?

Tags: c#, methods, console-application

In the method `nameCheck` I'm simply checking if any input is given.

At first I tried to change the method to `static` and made a `public` variable, but then I realized it can't work because the Main method is `static` so `name` can't work. I searched the net and realized, that I don't have an object to use `nameCheck` so I solved that.

Now I don't know how to get the `string` in the method `nameCheck` to the `string` in my `Main` method.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hallo, wie heißt du?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Program a = new Program();
            a.nameCheck(name);

            Console.WriteLine("Hallo " + name);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private void nameCheck(string n)
        {
            if (n == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
                n = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make your private method static as well and just call it from your Main method.  No need to make a new instance of Program.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. I think you need to rethink your logic, what you are doing is probably not difficult. Perhaps you just need to run through a C# tutorial first?

Comment: In your code here, the name is made in your main, you pass it to be checked but actually return nothing from nameCheck, so, the name remains.. there is no passing it back..

Comment: You are asking the user for a new name if he doesn't enter one. But then you assign this string to the local variable `n` which is not the variable in the `Main`-method. You could have an instance variable which you read and write to instead. Or better, create a class `User` with a `Name`  property and initialize it.

Comment: 8 answers (so far) to this pretty terrible question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `nameCheck`:

```
n = Console.ReadLine();
```

This is just going to change the value of the local variable `n`.

Even if you change your method to `static`, you won't get the expected result.

For this to work, you need to return the new string:

```
private string nameCheck(string n)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein")
        n = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return n;
}
```

You'd then change your `Main` method:

```
Program a = new Program();
name = a.nameCheck(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return your values in your Method "nameCheck"

Try this in your Main Method:

```
Program a = new Program();
name = a.nameCheck(name);
```

Your nameCheck() Method should look like this:

```
private string nameCheck(string n)
{
    if (n == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
        n = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change return type of method nameCheck into string. And then call it from main method as like i did

```
    Console.WriteLine("Hallo, wie heißt du?");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Program a = new Program();
    string n=a.nameCheck(name);

    Console.WriteLine("Hallo " + n);


    Console.ReadLine();

private string nameCheck(string n)
{
    if (n == "")
    {
        // Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
        return "Geben Sie einen Namen ein";
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but rather some general tips:

`Program` is a pretty ubiquitous name. And this effectively mirrors your whole program.

C# is object-oriented, but that doesn't mean you can just make everything an object and add functions. The access modifiers and `static` each have their purposes.

Your class `Program` has a private method `nameCheck`. Have you asked yourself why `private` or why not `static` but an instance method?
The C# compiler allows it, but you didn't quite get the semantics right.

Since `nameCheck` is a completely stateless method you'd rather define it `static`. Also, change `Program` to something, which actually **reflects your intent**.
A whole other way (and the better OO one, IMO) would be to have a class like `Name` with a `string` data member for the name and a method `nameCheck`. The `Main` method can know instantiate the class and call `nameCheck` as it pleases.

---

I'd advise to revisit the basics of OOP and read up about it, especially encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of opportunities to your question.

Define your method to change the passed string directly using `ref`:

```
private void nameCheck(ref string n)
{
    if (n == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
        n = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
nameCheck(ref name);
```

**Second** one would be changing your method to non-static and use a member-variable:

```
class program
{
    private string name;

    Main() 
    {
        //...
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Name = p.checkName();
    }

    private void nameCheck()
    {
        if (this.name == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
            this.name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Third** one using a return-value for your method:

```
class program
{
    Main() 
    {
        //...
        Program p = new Program();
        string name = ...
        name = p.checkName(name);
    }

    private string nameCheck(string name)
    {
        if (name == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

As an asside consider to use `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))` instead of checking against `=="`.

Answer (score 0):

To return a string from your nameCheck void you would actually need to chance it from a void to a string so...

```
private string nameChech(string input)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
         return string.Empty;
    /* other checking code */
    return input // you can do any string that may have been altered/appended/etc
}
```

so now in your program.cs you could do!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hallo, wie heißt du?");
        string name = nameCheck(console.ReadLine());
        if (name == string.Empty)
        {
            console.WriteLine(/* no name provided */);
            return;
        }
        /* other checking code */          
        Program a = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("Hallo " + name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that nameCheck doesn't return anything (the return type is `void`).

Try the following:

```
    private string nameCheck(string n)
    {
        if (n == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie einen Namen ein");
            n = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return n;
    }
```

and then you need to change

```
        a.nameCheck(name);
```

to

```
        name = a.nameCheck(name);
```

Best read up on return types and on pointers - try to find a good tutorial for those.